# Not able to resolve kotlin-gradle-plugin after upgrade Kotlin version from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

When I upgrade Kotlin version from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 I get this error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0:
          - gradle70JavadocElements
          - gradle70RuntimeElements
          - gradle70SourcesElements
          - javadocElements
          - runtimeElements
          - sourcesElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'gradle70RuntimeElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0 declares a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides a library but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.jvm.environment' with value 'standard-jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'jvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please always provide a good *specific* title to your question. That you run into a problem is indicative of 99% of the questions posted to [so].